# Amount of connections to Heroku DB in Spring

Tags: java, spring, database, heroku

I'm making my Web App in Spring.
Is it normal that it takes 10 connections to this PostrgreSQL database?
If not, how can I configure to take less?
Anyway, I think that my small app will works fine with only "one tube" of access.
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YwzS.png)

Comment: 10 is the default number of connections for the datasource, so yes it is. Are you really sure you only need a single connection, this also means that you can have 1 user at a time in your application!.

Comment: OK, make sense! Do you know for eg how to reduce connections on my local dev sesrver side or datagrip side to one?

Comment: Configure the max number of connections.